# Is neutralized and dried suphuric acid still a hazard? Is it still acidic to touch?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, acid-base

I mistakenly put a sulfuric acid drain cleaner in  my bathroom  sink. Some of it spilled into the bathroom in my basement. I cleaned it up using baking soda, but I'm concerned if I missed any, whether it will still be acidic after it dries. Does sulfuric acid lose its acidity after it dries?

Comment: Dried sulphuric acid is kind of nonsense. If you let a drop of the acid to be exposed to open air, it will never get dry and solid. It is still liquid, with acid concentration depending on air humidity, as it is hygroscopic. After acid neutralization ( i.e. not drying ) by solid baking soda, you can still neutralize the small residual amounts by washing contaminated surface by the baking soda solution.

Answer (score 2):

It reacted with the baking soda and is no longer sulfuric acid, but much safer sodium sulfate. If you're unsure, add more baking soda until it no longer fizzes.

The remaining white powder is a mix of baking soda or $\ce{NaHCO3}$, and sodium sulfate, $\ce{Na2SO4}$. It safe to wipe up with a damp rag and fairly harmless to touch. Just avoid getting the powder in your eyes.

Comment: It appears that you've voted to close the question giving the reason "unclear what you're asking" and yet you've posted an answer, which implies that the question wasn't unclear to you after all. I understand it might have been an impulsive decision during reviewing, but please try to act more coherent in the future.

Comment: Actually, I believe the question does not necessarily belong in Chemistry StackEchange because of its quality, but gave an answer to assuage the fears of the inquirer.